# How can I open wordpad or notepad in Jpanel in java?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to open `notepad++` in `Jpanel` but am not able to do it. Can anyone please help me on how to do it?

I read about an API JDIC but didnt find anything about opening text editors in `JPanel`. Is there any other API which can help me accomplish the task.

Comment: You can run `notepad++` in other process

Comment: Your not likely to be able to achieve this using a light weight container like `JPanel`.  You "might" be able to achieve it using a `Component` or `Container`, but it would depend on the capabilities of the program you are trying to embed

Answer (score 4):

Notepad++ is a standalone application. It is not distributed as a dll from which you can reuse certain elements, nor is it a system control.

You can only run it as a separate process from java, but you will be otherwise unable to integrate with it.

You can, however, take advantage of syntax highlighting of [JSyntaxPane](https://code.google.com/p/jsyntaxpane/) component - perhaps that will be enough.

Comment: I recommended that, too =)

Comment: Is there any inbuild editor in java which is similar to notepad++ that is which support multiple tabs, can open and close files?

Comment: You would have to implement it. There are tabs, there are TextAreas, the world is your oyster

Comment: I was just thinking that if there is a text editor in java then why to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Is there any API in java which provides me with notepad like editor?

Comment: Jsyntaxpane is what u need

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is to embed `notepad++` in `JPanel` which is not possible.  A `JPanel` can only contain `JComponents`

If all you need is syntax highlighting and indenting facilities that notepad++ provides then you need to use `JSyntaxPane`.

*Download*: http://code.google.com/p/jsyntaxpane/

Answer (score 2):

Use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your_executable_file")` for run your application in separated process. [Read it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html).